# Sending webcam snapshots directly to amazon s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, webcam

I'm working on a javascript code that records images from webcam and sends them directly to amazon storage via REST API. I've checked some JS webcam plugins like JQuery webcam plugin (http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) and JPEGCam (http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/), but I couldn't make them send compressed data as custom-formatted REST query. Does anyone know how to:

- capture image from webcam from javascript
- compress it
- send from javascript to amazon s3 directly?

I know it is possible to get raw image data and compress it manually in javascript, but I hoped for a native method that would be both more efficient and easier to use...